# Mongodb getting the entire sub-schema for all results

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have a simple schema as below,

```
Post {
createdAt: Date,
createdBy: ObjectID,
...
}

User {
_id: ObjectID,
name: String,
...
}
```

When a user creates such a record, I save it with his ID.

For the Post collection, I want to create a query and retrieve the records, with sending the entire User schema for all results. For example, a simple result:

```
 [
    {
    createdAt: xxx,
    createdBy: {
       _id: xxx,
       name: xxx
    },
    ...
 ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with `population`, like this:

```
Posts.find({}).populate('createdBy');
```